# Is it possible to access a server using Client side Scripting Language

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to ask, can I access the remote server using pure client side scripting language like Javascript, Jquery, ajax


I want to do but there is CORS problem, We can solve it with server side scripting language but how javascript can help us to do this

Comment: @programmer_1 cross origin resource sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a remote server you can either use [JSONP](http://www.json-p.org/) to receive data or have the remote server enable CORS, which may not be possibly as you may not have access to it, but if you do [this](http://enable-cors.org/) will show you how to enable CORS.

Most web apis support a JSONP request, however. You can use it by passing an additional parameter to the (script-)request and implement a callback function of the same name.

```
<script src="remote.server.com/api?jsonp=myCallback"></script>

<script>
  function myCallback( data ) {
     // do some stuff
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How I can check if the remote server is JSONP enabled or not

Comment: Either check the API description or try the usual parameters `jsonp=` or `callback=` if they return a proper result.

Comment: When I tried to check the following error occurs '405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL'

Comment: Is the API even open for public access via http?

Comment: I want to access youtube... I dontknow about it

Comment: I think you should have a closer look at the [API spec](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/overview.html) then or describe your _problem_ in working with it in more detail.

Comment: You can't use JSONP for POST requests, it's not possible at all on any version of any browser for low level reasons.